# How to disable serial logging in Homestead?

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have a process taking 100% of my CPU for a few days now and it's extremely annoying. The process is `VBoxHeadless`. After some research I found out that this change to Vagrantfile can fix it:

```
$enable_serial_logging = false
```

I'm not sure how to edit Vagrant config for Homestead. Should I just edit Vagrantfile or is there syntax in Homestead.yaml to do that?

Also, where should I put this line?

Comment: Not an vagrant/ruby expert, but from somewhat example [here](https://gist.github.com/dalekurt/5c0dbaf26b96f4504011#file-vagrantfile-L92-L95) I would say that option and functionality should be set somewhere after [this](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/blob/master/scripts/homestead.rb#L22) line. It could be passed from `Homestead.yaml` over `Vagrantfile` it should be passed before [line 36](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/blob/master/Vagrantfile#L36). Disclaimer: not tested, just assuming.

Comment: I have no idea how to use Vagrant variables in Homestead.yaml though.

Comment: Check [here](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/blob/master/scripts/homestead.rb#L59-L62) in `homestead.rb` file. `settings['variable_from_Homestead.yml']` is used as pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem.

I added it towards the top of the Vagrantfile and it seemed to do the trick:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

require 'json'
require 'yaml'

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION ||= "2"
confDir = $confDir ||= File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__))

homesteadYamlPath = confDir + "/Homestead.yaml"
homesteadJsonPath = confDir + "/Homestead.json"
afterScriptPath = confDir + "/after.sh"
customizationScriptPath = confDir + "/user-customizations.sh"
aliasesPath = confDir + "/aliases"

$enable_serial_logging = false

...
```

Just make sure after editing you run `vagrant destroy` and `vagrant up` for the change to be applied.